# Scala - Correct types for custom map implementation

Tags: scala, types, multimap

I am trying to implement an immutable MultiMap (in my case it's also sorted). The signature looks as follows:

```
class SortedMultiMap[K,V] private (private val delegate: SortedMap[K, Set[V]])
                                  (implicit ord: Ordering[K])
      extends SortedMap[K, Set[V]]
      with SortedMapLike[K, Set[V], SortedMultiMap[K,V]]
```

As you can see it delegates most operations to the encapsulated delegate map. A few extra methods are added for the MultiMap functionality itself (similar to the [scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap)). If you are interested in the full source code, check out the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mucaho/10750215).

I am content with my current implementation, except for the `+` method:

### Desired `+` implementation

```
override def +[B1 >: Set[V]](kv: (K, B1)) = new SortedMultiMap(delegate + kv)
```

This gives a type mismatch error: `found: (K, B1)` `required: (K, Set[V])`. **Is there a way to fix this?** If I understand correctly `B1` represents `_ >: Set[V]`.

### Current `+` implementation

The current implementation is taken from a [similar question about custom map implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13597951/3041008)

```
override def +[B1 >: Set[V]](kv: (K, B1)): SortedMap[K, B1] = delegate + kv // general case
def +(kv: (K,Set[V])): SortedMultiMap[K, V] = new SortedMultiMap(delegate + kv) // specific case
```

Here a general implementation is provided and am overloaded method is provided for a specific case. This works fine when manually calling the method, but other methods like `++`, `updated`, etc. also rely on this method and thus return the wrong collection (`SortedMap` instead of the desired `SortedMultiMap`).

Answer (score 1):

```
override def +[B1 >: Set[V]](kv: (K, B1)) = new SortedMultiMap(delegate + kv)
```

Well, if `B1` is e.g. `Object` (which satisfies `Object :> Set[V]`), and you add `(K, Object)` to `delegate`, you'll get a `SortedMap[K, Object]` and obviously can't make it into a `SortedMultiMap`. If you want to avoid this, you have two options:

1. Not extend `SortedMap` (you can still extend `SortedMapLike`) (doesn't work, see comments).
2. Match on the type of value:

   ```
   override def +[B1 >: Set[V]](kv: (K, B1)): SortedMap[K, B1] = kv._2 match {
     // may need some massaging to persuade the compiler
     case v: Set[a] => new SortedMultiMap(delegate + (kv._1, v)) 
     case _ => delegate + kv
   }
   ```

   Note that in this case the static return type is always `SortedMap`.

Another way is to add an implicit conversion from `SortedMap[K, Set[V]]` to `SortedMultiMap[K,V]`. This way if `B1` is `Set[V]`, the result will still be `SortedMap` but you are free to call `SortedMultiMap`-specific methods or otherwise use it where `SortedMultiMap` is expected.

Comment: The first option does not seem to work for me. I still have to implement `override def +[B1 >: Set[V]](kv: (K, B1)): SortedMap[K, B1] = ???`. That's exactly the same issue as when extending `SortedMap`. Do I have to change something else in the signature in addition to **not** extending `SortedMap`?

Comment: I thought `SortedMapLike.+` returned `This` (type parameter of `SortedMapLike`), but it actually returns `SortedMap` http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.SortedMapLike So the first solution doesn't work, sorry.